# Replace source word with containing /(forward slash) to destination word in VI editor command window

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vim, grep

I'm facing problem while cmake compilation wherein, there are thousands of `/root/repo/` are there & I want to replace with `/repo/` . Because of `/` in the source word the command

```
:%s/srcWrd/dstwrd/gc
```

is not working. Kindly guide here about how to proceed.

sample input : A line in the file contains

```
/root/repo/my-gerrit/myData.cpp
```

It should look like

```
/repo/my-gerrit/myData.cpp
```

I've tried below command inside file, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
:%s\/root\/\repo\/repo/gc
```

Comment: not entirely sure what you are asking, but you can escape a / with a \ so /root/repo/ becomes \/root\/repo\/

Comment: Thanks @rob but it doesn't work. I tried `:%s\/root\/\repo\/repo/gc` inside `vim try.txt`. It creates a newline and not replacing also.

Comment: you're missing the normal slashes, they are still needed.

Comment: I added the detailed problem in the question. Please have a relook

Comment: `:%s/\/root//` gives me the result you were looking for. It removes the /root rather than replacing it.

Comment: Again, because you somehow ignored my comment: you're missing the normal slashes, they are still needed.

Comment: Your replace line is wrong because you missed the `/` command.  It should be `:%s/\/root\/repo/\/repo/gc`

Comment: Thanks @rob and all. I did simple mistake. Got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you gave, with a file containing

```
/root/repo/my-gerrit/myData.cpp
```

This can be changed to

```
/repo/my-gerrit/myData.cpp
```

with the command `:%s/\root//gc`.

You attempted `%s\/root\/\repo\/repo/gc`, which lacks the normal forward slashes. To replace `/root/repo/` with `/repo/`, the command would be `%s/\/root\/repo\//\/repo\//gc`

Note that forward slashes that you want to replace are escaped with `\`. Forward slashes that is part of the command is *not* escaped.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working.

Comment: It's just a summary of the comments to your question. That's why I posted it as community wiki :)

Answer (score 2):

While escaping the forward slashes with backslashes is an option, it's much easier to use a different separator altogether.

Such as:

```
:%s#/root/repo/#/repo/#gc
```

Or:

```
:%s+/root/repo/+/repo/+gc
```

Or:

```
:%s,/root/repo/,/repo/,gc
```

You can use almost any symbol as a separator on the `:s` command, so it should be easy to find one that doesn't require escaping that symbol in the pattern or replacement.

See also [`:help E146`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#E146)

Comment: The easiest, this answer should be upvoted. Using a different sed separator is the best way to get rid of `/` handling/escaping.